# como habilito los sockets en xampp?

Tags: php, socket, composer

hola comunidad me pueden decir como habilitar los sockets en xampp para php hice lo siguente:

primero configure el php.ini en esta parte: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y dentro de mi carpeta de mi proyecto puse un index.php con lo siguiente

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

lo cual me muestra esto que dice que ya esta habilitado los socket:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego ejectuo este comando para instalar una dependencia:

```
composer require php-amqplib/php-amqplib
```

pero me manda este error:

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for php-amqplib/php-amqplib ^2.11 -> satisfiable by php-amqplib/php-amqplib[v2.11.0].
    - php-amqplib/php-amqplib v2.11.0 requires ext-sockets * -> the requested PHP extension sockets is missing from your system.

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

se supone que ya estan habilitada la dll de los socket en xampp no ?? 
por que sigue pasando ese error que me falta??

Comment: Si estas usando la distribución de Bitnami debes considerar esta pregunta: ¿ En qué ubicación ejecutas [composer] ? Es posible que tengas al menos dos instalaciones de php, una global que no has tocado y otra ligada a la instalación de xampp, en la que hiciste el cambio en php.ini.

Comment: excelente muchas gracias por ese comentario no lo había pensado y si tengo dos instalaciones de xampp ya modifique el archivo del otro y ya funciono

Answer (score 1):

solución a mi propia pregunta, para habilitar los sockets en xampp primero configure el php.ini en esta parte, solo se debe quitar el `;` donde dice `extension=sockets`:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

dentro de mi carpeta del proyecto puse un index.php con el siguiente código para que me mostrara si ya se habilitaron los `sockets` después se puede borrar esta pagina index:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

así se muestra que ya están habilitados:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ese fue el procedimiento que deben usar para habilitar los sockets en xampp, mi problema era diferente yo tenia dos instalaciones de xampp lo cual me creaba un conflicto por lo cual no se habilitaban tuve que modificar los puertos, pero en si para habilitar los sockets la configuración que muestro es la correcta.