# Obteniendo DbUpdateException al agregar una fila

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework

Estoy tratando de agregar un registro en una tabla, pero no funciona. El mensaje de error me dice que no puedo insertar un valor explícito en la columna de identidad Productos, pero no sé si lo estoy haciendo bien. ¿Quizás hay algo que no entiendo acerca de la navegación de entidades o mis modelos no están correctamente vinculados?

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Productos' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.
```

Este es el código que falla (`await context.SaveChangesAsync();`):

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Guid>> Post(Carrito carrito)
        {
            context.Add(carrito);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();          
            return carrito.Id;
        }
```

Estos son los modelos de entidad involucrados:

```
public class ArticuloCarrito
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Carrito")]
        public Guid CarritoId { get; set; }

        public Producto Producto { get; set; }

        public int Cantidad { get; set; }

        public decimal Total {
            get
            {
                return Producto.Precio_venta * Cantidad;
            }
        }
        public virtual Carrito Carrito { get; set; }

        //public string Key => $"{producto.SKU}";
    }

    public class Carrito
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ArticuloCarrito> Articulos { get; set; }

        public decimal Total
        {
            get
            {
                decimal total = 0;
                foreach (var item in Articulos)
                {
                    total += item.Total;
                }
                return total;
            }           
        }
        public DateTime UltimoAcceso { get; set; }
        public int TiempoDeVidaEnSegundos { get; set; } = 1800; // 30 minutos para que vuelva
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu error está en la falta de un par de decoradores para decirle a EF que se manejan los GUID como llaves primarias.

```
public class Carrito
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

**Actualización**

Un par de detalles importante:

```
[key]
```

Normalmente la utilizo para especificar cuál es la propiedad de llave primaria. Según Entity Framework, esto es innecesario tal y como mencionas en el comentario: "*si pones Id ya lo interpreta como primary key y que solo si pones por ejemplo Id_Cliente o IdCliente es cuando debes de poner [key]*", digamos que aquí me ganó la costumbre.

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

Este decorador especifica que el valor de la propiedad será generada por el motor de base de datos durante el `Insert`. Cabe mencionar que esta propiedad no podrá ser actualizada debido a que es una llave.

Comment: yo había leído que en una clase modelo si pones Id ya lo interpreta como primary key y que solo si pones por ejemplo Id_Cliente o IdCliente es cuando debes de poner [key], [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] este para que se usa ??

Comment: @JasielTorres respuesta actualizada :D

Comment: ok muchas gracias por tu tiempo y ayuda, con esto ya entendí un poco mejor de como ayudan los decoradores a indicarle a entity framework las propiedades a tratar

Comment: Vale bro, por cierto, esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/331406/como-habilito-los-sockets-en-xampp lograste solucionarla, sería bien interesante que puedas compartir en la respuesta los pasos que realizaste, serás el héroe de más usuarios que tengan el mismo problema o algo muy parecido :D

Comment: amm es que los pasos que describo en la propia pregunta son la respuesta para habilitar los sockets estaba todo bien, mi problema se debió a que tenia dos instalaciones de xampp y creaba un conflicto pero en si el habilitar sockets estaba bien

Comment: Esos detalles, en la respuesta por favor :D

Comment: listo ya quedo editada la respuesta